# Lingering firefox.exe

Tags: windows, firefox, process

It seems like every other time I try to launch Firefox, I get an error message saying Firefox is already running. While I see no Firefox windows displayed, investigating the `Processes` tab in `Task Manager` sure enough reveals a `firefox.exe` instance running. After ending this process, I am able to launch Firefox normally.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

I can see two possible causes:

1. When I close Firefox, something goes wrong, and it closes its window but fails to kill its own process.
2. When I run Firefox, it hangs at some point after launch but before the window is shown. I assume that my attempt to launch it didn't register, and try to launch it again, getting the error dialog.

Comment: Have you tried if the problem happens in [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) too?

Comment: See this support link from Mozilla: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-already-running-not-responding?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Firefox+is+already+running+but+is+not+responding

Comment: @cremor It's a bit hard to test because it happens inconsistently.

Comment: Check this official article out: ["Firefox is already running but is not responding" error message - How to fix it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-already-running-not-responding)